# Survival of the Fittest activations and priority

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can someone please explain the ability of [Survival of the Fittest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Survival%20of%20the%20Fittest) and the stack?

Let say I have [Survival of the Fittest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Survival%20of%20the%20Fittest) out, and I have 1 creature in my hand, and I have priority.  Assuming I have unlimited mana, can I keep discarding a creature card and search for a creature card without an opponent casting any instant spell?

In other words, I will discard a creature card and have not pass priority, can an opponent cast instants like disenchant on the survival to stop me to continue searching?  If an opponent can cast disenchant before priority was pass, would I still need another creature card in my hand to be able to discard and search again?

I am unclear of how this would work.

Answer (score 6):

NB: [Survival of the Fittest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Survival%20of%20the%20Fittest) has an activated ability, not a triggered ability.  Triggered abilities always use the words "When", "Whenever", or "At".

You must discard a creature card (and pay green) as an activation cost in order to put the ability on the stack.  It now goes on the stack and your opponent gets priority before it resolves.  So they could destroy Survival of The Fittest before you get to search and add a card to your hand.

You still get to do your search and add the card, but obviously you cannot now use the ability again.

You can discard as many cards to it as you already have in your hand while retaining priority and not allowing your opponent to respond.  However, they will have a chance to respond before you're allowed to tutor up the new ones.

Comment: From reading an article on priority and the stack, an example was given:

Comment: Player a would cast Ancestral Recall, Player B would counter it, Player A use Mystical Tutor to search for cancel and put it on top of his library, then Player A plays Brainstorm to get Cancel in his hand, and counter Player B Counter Spell.

Comment: If that is the case, wouldn't discarding a creature card and searching for a creature card would resolved allowing me to get a creature card in my hand, then I can play it again before my opponenet cast disenchant?  In other words, when I discard, my ability is on top of the stack, that would resolved and then I can put another survival ability ontop of that stack and keep on going before the disenchant would resolve?  Is this correct?

Comment: Your first Survival is on the bottom of the stack, Disenchant goes above it and will resolve first.  If you had a *second* creature you could discard, you could then put that on top of disenchant and keep on survivaling until there are not more creatures in your library, keeping disenchant trapped on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Affe!  The only thing I'm unclear of now is when it talks about priority.  It says that I can play as many spells or abilities before I pass priority. Once I pass priority, then my oponenet can response.  Am I missing the point with Priority and Passinbg Priority and what it really mean?  If so, can you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you had 7 creatures in your hand, if you wanted you could say "I put 7 activations on the stack without passing priority." and discard all 7 to the survival.  Obviously this is kind of a bad play, because then if they cast disenchant in response to all 7, it will be on top and destroy your survival before you do any tutoring, so you couldn't carry on the tutor.  In the vast majority of cases you want to pass priority after each play and see if your opponent has any response.  (Maybe you would do it if you just looked at their hand and saw a [mtg:Krosan Grip]!)

Comment: I believe I still get to tutor even if I play 7 tutor on the survival.  I will get all my tutor but my survival will be disenchanted. If you look at Prodigical Sorcerer scenerio, Once I tap it to deal 1 damage to you, you can response by lightning bolt him.  He will die but you will still receive the 1 damage.

Comment: Yes you will get the 7 you paid for, you won't be able to continue digging beyond that.